# Populate table with field names and values taken from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, foreach

I'm trying to populate a table with values extracted from a mysql table stored in a wordpress database.

I've successfully managed to populate the body of the table with the record's fields but I'm wanting to show the column name for each particular field as a header. Note, I'm wanting the headers on the left and values on the right, not above and below like a traditional table.

I've tried using "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table_name" and also the mysqli_fetch_field_direct function but I can't work out a way of making it work in the format I'm looking for where it's part of a loop. I'm new to PHP so I'm sure it's pretty simple but I'm completely stuck.

My code is below, I've marked where I want to echo the field names.

What I basically want to acheive is a table like this:

column_1_name:field_in_column_1

column_2_name:field_in_column_2

column_3_name:field_in_column_3

...

Thanks for any help in advance!

```
<table class="widefat">
 <tbody>
 <?php
    global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "consultation";


    $query  = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id=$_GET[id]";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    // Test if there was a query error
    if (!$results) {
        die ("Please select a user from the Consultation admin homepage");
    } else {
    foreach ($results as $record) {

    foreach ($record as $field) {

        echo "<tr><th>" . **THIS IS WHERE I WANT COLUMN NAME OF $field** . "</th><td> {$field}</td></tr>";
}
    }}
        ?> 
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Why are you using two `foreach` loops?

Comment: Thanks WebNovice, that worked perfectly. I was using 2 foreach loops because for some reason the $results variable contains an array which contains another array...not sure why. Is this a function of wpdb->get_results? Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks for your help

Comment: It would appear it is. I used get_row instead and I only needed one loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($results as $key => $val){
echo '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $val . '</td></tr>';
}
```